# Qt signal on buttongroup not connected

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

I have a buttongroup defined with two radiobuttons

```
buttonGroupFFTDimension = new QButtonGroup(this);
buttonGroupFFTDimension->addButton(ui->radioButton1D, 1);
buttonGroupFFTDimension->addButton(ui->radioButton2D, 2);
buttonGroupFFTDimension->setExclusive(true);
ui->radioButton1D->setChecked(true);
```

The connect also compiles

```
connect(this->buttonGroupFFTDimension, static_cast<void(QButtonGroup::*)(int)>(&QButtonGroup::buttonClicked),
        this, &MainWindow::on_buttonGroupFFTDimension_buttonClicked);
```

but it throws and error at runtime

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_buttonGroupFFTDimension_buttonClicked(int)
```

I admit that I am not familiar with the new connect syntax, but also do not see the obvious error. What is wrong?

Comment: You could show how you define the slot: `on_buttonGroupFFTDimension_buttonClicked`

Comment: The message shown is because you are using `Qt Designer` and it uses the `connectSlotsByName` method to connect various elements, it recognizes the format `on_somesender_somesignal`, and in your case matches your slot, try changing the name of your slot, run `make clean` and then `qmake`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message shown is because you are using Qt Designer and it uses the `connectSlotsByName` method to connect various elements, it recognizes the format `on_somesender_somesignal`, and in your case matches your slot.

- First solution: It iss unnecessary to use the `connect` function, this will automatically do it. Also I think that the slot does not have as parameter the type int that requires.

In your case the slot should be as follows:

```
private  slots:
    void on_buttonGroupFFTDimension_buttonClicked (int val);
```

- Another possible solution is to rename the slot, after that you run `make clean` and `qmake`.